# Shell Scripting - check java bin

Tags: java, unix, shell

On a unix machine, how can I write a shell script for checking if 'java bin' directory has been included in $PATH env. variable?

Comment: You've asked 6 questions on the site, haven't accepted any answers, and only done 4 upvotes.  Learn how to use the site or people will stop answering your questions.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will be doing this from now on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's probably simplest to use `which`:

```
which java || exit 1
```

Comment: @Paul I see 14:13:59Z for both

Comment: Yeah, but yours shows up ahead of mine, so you must have hit the database ahead of mine.

Comment: @Paul Ah, I guess checking the ID would be the logical way to find out :)

Answer (score 7):

```
if which java >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
  echo yes
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the directory name can be anything, this would be a bit hard to check by looking at the $PATH variable, but you could try looking at the return value of a command like `which javac`.

Answer (score 0):

`which` is appropriate, but only checks for your command defined in $PATH. What if javac is not defined in $PATH but it is installed somewhere else? In that extreme case, you use `find` or `locate` to find where `javac` is.